# WPF C# Application I get 2 main windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am really new to WPF and c#, and have some questions about how the applications are initialized.  I am going through some tutorials on LINQ classes in the hopes that I can bind all of my SQL Server data with observableCollections.

One of the examples I found has a start like so (in the App.xaml.cs file):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow app = new MainWindow();
        ProductViewModel context = new ProductViewModel();
        app.DataContext = context;
        app.Show();
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get 2 main windows.  The commands above execute and open the first one, but then a second one gets called from some system code which I can't see (I can see in dissasembler, but that does not really help).  So it seems that the application that VS set up for me has a standard entry, but the sample code (from Rachel Lim) does not do this.  I have searched for differences in various files (like App.g.i.cs which has the void Main() call) and both my application and the sample are the same.  I am trying to "take control" of the application to handle creating my observablecollections with the LINQ classes.  Is anyone familiar enough with VS and C# to give me some hints on what might be happening?

Comment: Check your `Application.xaml` file, there's probably a "Startup" element there.

Comment: @CodingGorilla . . . thank you.  I had checked that, but did not see that difference . . . doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in your `App.xaml` which often has the following:

```
Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If your `App.xaml.cs` opens a window in one of the events as you have demonstrated, then you need to make sure to remove that `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` in your `Application` element.